# DFS class that implements Iterator<T>

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, tree, iterator

I want to realize DFS for my own generic tree with my own nodes.
Nodes have this fields

```
private T value;
private final List<Node<T>> listOfChildren;
```

And Tree.class has only Node root field.
My DFS realization is working fine, but it's my first work with iterator and I don't understand how I should @Override methods.

```
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

public class DFSAlgorithm<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private final Stack<Iterator<T>> stack = new Stack<>();

    private List<Node<T>> listOfChildren;

    public void DFS(Node<T> vertex) {
        System.out.println("DFS start");
        Stack<Node<T>> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(vertex);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Node<T> node = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(node.getValue());
            for (Node<T> tNode : node.getListOfChildren()) {
                stack.push(tNode);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.listOfChildren != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return null;
    }


}
```

My Node.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private final List<Node<T>> listOfChildren;

    public Node(){
        super();
        listOfChildren = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    public Node(T value){
        this();
        setValue(value);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getListOfChildren() {
        return listOfChildren;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getNumberOfChildren() {
        return listOfChildren.size();
    }

    public void addChildren(Node<T> child) {
        listOfChildren.add(child);
    }
}
```

I don't understand where I should write Node and where I should write Iterable.
Should I write this methods for stack in DFS or for Tree?
Can you explain this, please, I'm new in java

Comment: An `Iterable<T>` contains `T` which can be iterated over, providing an `#iterator` method. That method returns an `Iterator<T>`, which actually performs the iteration. In essence, a `Tree` would be `Iterable`, and `DFSAlgorithm` would be a manual `Iterator` for some `Node<T>`. Overridden methods are just that: they will be called instead of the default/abstract inherited method from `Iterator<T>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *@Rogue* has said in the comments, your Tree should implement interface `Iterable`, i.e. it needs to override `iterator()` method, which is meant to provide a mean of traversal over this tree.

`DFSAlgorithm` in turn should be an `Iterator`, i.e. `MyTree.iterator()` would return a new instance of `DFSAlgorithm`. And `DFSAlgorithm` needs to implement the contract of the `Iterator` interface by overriding methods `next()` and `hasNext()`.

There's a few things to note:

- Method `DFS()` is not needed. The logic of Depth first search algorithm should be reflected in the implementations of `next()` and `hasNext()` (by the way, method name `DFS()` is not aligned with Java naming conventions).
- A Stack, which is used a mean of traversal in DFS algorithm, should be an instance variable of the iterator implementation (no need to create another instantiate of the stack as you've done and store it in a local variable). And Stack should be populated with the *root-node* of the Tree while instantiating the iterator.
- Field `List<Node<T>> listOfChildren` is redundant, it's not required in the classic DFS implementation and in this case as well. Having only a Stack is sufficient to perform traversal of a Tree.
- Class `java.util.Stack` is legacy and not recommenced to be used. Instead, when you need an implementation of the Stack data structure, it's advisable to utilize implementations of the `Deque` interface.
- Method `remove()` has a default implementation which throws `UnsupportedOperationException` (which is semantically more suitable, than `ConcurrentModificationException` that can be observed in your code). If you're not going to implement the functionality for removing nodes by the means of iterator, there's no need to override this method.
- `ConcurrentModificationException` is meant to guard against structural modifications (i.e. modifications that affect the size of the data structure) that happen during the iteration process, which can lead to the situation when iteration is unaware of the actual state of the data structure. The common practice is to introduce a couple of modification counters and compare their values at the very beginning of the call `Iterator.next()`. If you wonder how it might be implemented, have a look at the standard Collections from JDK.

That's how the implementation might look like:

```
public class MyTree<T> implements Iterable<T> {
    
    private Node<T> root;
    
    // constructor of the Tree, etc.
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new DFSAlgorithm<>(root);
    }
    
    public class DFSAlgorithm<T> implements Iterator<T> {
        
        private final Deque<Node<T>> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    
        public DFSAlgorithm(Node<T> vertex) {
            this.stack.push(vertex);
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }
        
        @Override
        public T next() {
            Node<T> next = stack.pop();
            
            for (Node<T> tNode: next.getListOfChildren()) {
                stack.push(tNode);
            }
            
            return next.getValue();
        }
    }
    
    public class Node<T> {
        // you code without changes here
    }
}
```

Comment: What should i do to start dfs now (How can I call dfs)? And can you explain, please, why my iterator works with generic type <T>.  Iterator should work with type <Node<T>>, isn't it?

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry Not sure if I understood your comment correctly. If you need to be able to traverse the whole tree in one go, then you can add `dfs()` method as well, [that's how it might look like](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/wME). The code I've provided is a "ready to go" solution of how to use `DFSAlgorithm` as an iterator.

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry *" why my iterator works with generic type <T>. Iterator should work with type <Node<T>>, isn't it?"* - the `Node<T>` is an implementation detail of your data structure that usually shouldn't exposed to the outside world. Because the code that uses your Tree is concerned with storing and retrieving values of type `T` from it, without having any knowledge of Nodes (similarly you don't need to know how your phone works internally in order to use it).

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry Of course, you can make the iterator return a node `Node<T>`, but I doubt if you really want it. Here is a contract of the [Iterator.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html#next()). If you want the method `next()` to return the value `T` of the node (but not the node), then your iterator should be declared as `DFSAlgorithm<T> implements Iterator<T>` (that's what you can see in the code above).

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry On the other hand, if you declare the iterator as `DFSAlgorithm<Node<T>> implements Iterator<Node<T>>`, then method `next()` should be implemented to retrieve the whole node `Node<T>`, not the value `T`. Which would be inconvenient and breaks the encapsulation by exposing implementation detains of your Tree (which is not great, because external code should not depend on the implementation details).

Comment: One more question. What if I want to make DFS and BFS iterators. Should I write two different @Overrides of iterator for DFS and BFS or it's impossible?

Comment: @HandcraftingCountry While overriding `iterator()` method in your Tree, you need to provide an implementation (a **particular** implementation). In practice, collections have only one iterator. You can implement more than one iterator, but method `iterator()` is parameterless, so there's no way (*almost*) to get different instances of iterator at different calls. As a work-around, you can introduce a field in the Tree class, which would allow determining what kind of iterator should be provided.